# Does a whitening transformation of the prior affect the performance of elliptical slice sampling?

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-process, elliptical-distribution, whitening

I have been using [elliptical slice sampling (ESS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0175) with much success lately and I have a question I can't seem to figure out myself.

Does a whitening transformation of the prior affect ESS performance? In other words, does ESS take advantage of the particular covariance structure to propose better moves?

To clarify, say my prior and likelihood for **problem 1** are $$p(x) = N(0, \Sigma) \ \text{ and } \ \mathcal{L}(x) = \text{some function of $x$}$$

Using a whitening transformation $$x = L z \text{ where } L L^T = \Sigma$$ transform to **problem 2** with prior and likelihood $$p(z) = N(0,I) \ \text{ and } \ \mathcal{L}^*(z) = \mathcal{L}(x(z))$$

*[Edited above expression to correct a mistake in $\mathcal{L}^*(z)$ thanks to @Xi'an]*

Problems 1 and 2 are equivalent, but the former exposes more information to ESS. Is ESS expected to perform better on problem 1?

Comment: Can you add a reference/link for elliptical slice sampling (ESS) ?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Done, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Why would you get a Jacobian in the likelihood function? The likelihood function is not a density in the parameter. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/132619/7224

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for the reply. The likelihood $\mathcal{L}(x)$ doesn't transform, the Jacobian comes from the transformation of the prior $p(x)$. Basically $\mathcal{L}(x) \times p(x) = \mathcal{L}(x(z)) \times p(z) \Big|{\partial z \over \partial x}\Big| := \mathcal{L}^*(z) \times p(z)$ so $\mathcal{L}^*(z)$ absorbs the Jacobian.

Comment: This derivation is not correct because $\mathcal L(x)p(x)$ is the density wrt the measure d$x$ while $\mathcal L(x(z))p(z)$ is the density wrt the measure d$z$.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for pointing that out, you are completely right. I edited the question accordingly. And this makes me think intuitively that the answer to my question is leaning strongly towards a "no".